# Creating a Graph with Two X-Axes and Two Y-Axes with an Angled Secondary X-Axis

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm struggling to create a graph that is supposed to end up looking like this:

[image]

I have been able to graph everything except for the secondary x-axis at the top for temperature in degrees Celsius. Is this possible? I have the data points for where the modulus and loss factor intersect with each temperature line, but I do not have any other values regarding the temperature. If it can't be done, is there any way I could perhaps combine a contour graph with a scatter plot?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Here's a little sample of the data that I have.

```
Loss Factor 
Reduced Frequency   Frequency      Loss Factor       Temperature
1.53E-03            1.92E+00         1.91E+07         50
4.85E-03            3.02E+00         3.00E+07   
9.89E-03            3.90E+00         3.87E+07   
1.80E-02            5.04E+00         5.00E+07
Modulus         
Reduced Frequency   Frequency   Dynamic Modulus Temperature
1.07E-03            4.49E+02    4.49E+09    
3.06E-03            4.67E+02    4.67E+09    
8.34E-03            4.86E+02    4.86E+09    
9.93E-03            4.86E+02    4.86E+09    
2.20E-02            4.82E+02    4.82E+09    
4.42E-02            4.87E+02    4.87E+09          50



    50 Degrees Celsius  
   Reduced Frequency    D. Mod.
    2.77E-01            1.00E+11
    1.00E-03            1.00E+07
```

You can see that I only have the points of intersection of the temperature lines and the modulus/loss factor. I also I have the points at the end of each temperature line in relation to the y axis (dynamic modulus) and the x axis (reduced frequency).

Answer (score 0):

For the secondary axes you can see [double set fo axes](https://superuser.com/questions/655689/possible-to-have-two-y-axes-and-two-x-axes-on-same-chart)

- You can make your XY chart with both dataset.
- Then double click on one series, and on the Axis tab, select
  Secondary. It appears a secondary Y axis.
- Select "Chart Manu/Chart
  Options/Axes tab", uncheck the secondary Y box, and check the
  secondary X box.

[image: menu]

Answer (score -1):

Short answer is that it can't be done in Excel, as you described it in your question.  Excel is limited to four axes-primary and secondary X & Y.  However, there is often a way to trick Excel into doing what you want.  Without seeing the data (a sample would be a huge help), I would consider setting up your standard X & Y axes, then plot your modulus, loss factor AND angled X axis as three data series.  That will require that your data points be determined through formula based upon the standard axes which will probably require a fair bit of formula creativity-but the final result should have the appropriate appearance.  Good luck!

EDIT:  Based on your data, here's what I came up with (Excel 2010):  There are three data series, the modulus (red), loss factor (green) and the temperature "axis" line (gray).  The chart is an XY Chart, with both primary and secondary Y axes, a primary X axis and a "psuedo axis" which is really just a data series formated to look like an axis (two points with a line).  To finish the chart, you'll just need to add all of your primary series points, and one series (two points each) for each temperature line you want to show.[image: Angled X Axis Chart]

Comment: Thank you for your help, I added a sample of the data in the original post. I'm not quite understanding what you mean by having the angled X axis one of the data series. Could you please elaborate a little bit more? I am quite stumped on what to do.

Comment: @GlenM., did this work for you?  Please let me know if you need any extra help on it.